# Error on Dart Streams StreamTransformer int is not a subtype of EventSink<dynamic>

Tags: dart

Trying to learn Dart and generics now i have this code tring to learn about stream but i cants seem to get what is wrong with my code

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  StreamController<int> controller = new StreamController<int>();

  num i = 0;

  Future.doWhile(() {
    controller.add(i++);

    if (i == 100) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  var result = controller.stream.transform(
      StreamTransformer<int, EventSink<dynamic>>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (int number, EventSink<dynamic> sink) {
    if (number == 70) {
      sink.addError("Hit seventy");
    } else {
      sink.add(number);
    }
  }));

  result.listen((data) => print(data));
}
```

The above code bring me the following error

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'EventSink<dynamic>' of 'data'
EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart)
main.<anonymous closure> (file:///var/www/html/learning/dart/rr.dart:23:12)
HandlerEventSink.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:228:7)
SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StreamTransformer`'s generic types are the type of data in and the type of data out. Your transformer maps `int` to `dynamic` (though, as current written, it actually only emits `int`).

Your types on the `StringTransformer` constructor are incorrect. (Also, it isn't necessary to repeat the types on the definition of the `handleData` lambda, since they can be deduced from the transformer's types.)

Try:

```
void main() {
  StreamController<int> controller = new StreamController<int>();

  num i = 0;

  Future.doWhile(() {
    controller.add(i++);
    return i < 100;
  });

  var result = controller.stream.transform(
    StreamTransformer<int, dynamic>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (number, sink) {
        if (number == 70) {
          sink.addError("Hit seventy");
        } else {
          sink.add(number);
        }
      },
    ),
  );

  result.listen((data) => print(data));
}
```